# C++ Variable-sized arrays using stdin and stdout

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to solve this problem on variable-sized arrays but I'm getting a compilation error. Not exactly sure where I went wrong.

[Problem can be accessed in this PDF](https://hackerrank-challenge-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/14507-variable-sized-arrays-English?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1576723269&Signature=2MUOS7l2pqIrEn7CZur5Us0y3Dw%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3Dvariable-sized-arrays-English.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf)

My solution attempt is as follows:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int n,q,size,elem,index,smallindex;

    //input of n and q
    cin>>n>>q;

    //declare the array a 
    int* bigarr = new int[q];

    //assign the individual arrays to each element of the array a
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        //input of size of the individual array
        cin>>size;
        int* smallarr = new int[size];

        for (int j=0; j<size; ++j){
            smallarr[j] = cin>>elem;
        }
        bigarr[i] = smallarr;
    }

    //obtain index queries
    for (int k=0; k<n; ++k){
        cin>>index;
        cin>>smallindex;
        cout<<bigarr[index][smallindex];
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` to solve the problem.  There is no need to get into all of these weeds of dynamic memory management.  The question you linked to doesn't care what underlying structure you use, as long as you can answer the question.  Note that using `vector` does not give you the solution to the problem you linked to -- it *does* allow you to concentrate on the question without having to deal with all of this memory management correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this statement:

```cpp
bigarr[i] = smallarr;
```

`smallarr` is an `int*` pointer, but `bigarr` is also an `int*`, ie an array of `int`, so `bigarr[i]` is a single `int`.  You can't assign an `int*` pointer to an `int` value.

If you want `bigarr` to be an array of pointers to other arrays, you need to declare `bigarr` as `int**` instead of `int*`, and then use `new int*[q]` to allocate it.

```cpp
int** bigarr = new int*[q];
```

Also, on this statement:

```cpp
smallarr[j] = cin>>elem;
```

The expression `cin>>elem` returns an `istream&` reference to `cin`, it does not return the `int` value read into `elem`, like you are expecting. So you can't use the result of that expression directly in the assignment to `smallarr[j]`.  You will have to read `elem` and assign it to `smallarr` in separate statements:

```cpp
cin>>elem;
smallarr[j] = elem;
```

That said, note that your code is leaking all of the allocated arrays since there are no calls to `delete[]` anywhere.  You need to add them:

```cpp
int** bigarr = new int*[q];
...
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    ...
    int* smallarr = new int[size];
    ...
    bigarr[i] = smallarr;
}
...
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    delete[] bigarr[i]; // <-- here
}
delete[] bigarr; // <-- here
```

Though, you really should be using `std::vector` instead of using `new[]`/`delete[]` manually at all (you already have `#include <vector>`):

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int> > bigarr(q);
...
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    ...
    std::vector<int> smallarr(size);
    for (int j=0; j<size; ++j){
        ...
        smallarr[j] = elem;
    }
    bigarr[i] = smallarr;

    /* alternatively:
    bigarr[i].resize(size);
    for (int j=0; j<size; ++j){
        ...
        bigarr[i][j] = elem;
    }
    */
}
```

I also see is that you are using `q` to allocate `bigarr`, but then you use `n` to loop through `bigarr`.  You don't need two separate variables.  Use either `n` or `q` for both tasks, and get rid of the other variable.

Unless you really intend to allocate more slots then you want to fill in.  In which case, your outer loop needs to ensure that it doesn't exceed both `n` and `q`:

```cpp
for (int i=0; (i<n) && (i<q); ++i){
```

Or:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<std::min(n,q); ++i){
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my misconceptions thoroughly. May I check with you why the following line of code - int** bigarr = new int*[q] is correct and that in ** bigarr = new int[q] is not?

Comment: @Prav I addressed that in my answer. Go read it more carefully.